# MongoDB: find query returning repeated values

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591ec4b8e1f71c0caf406f2a"),
    "methods" : {
        "head" : [
            {
                "host" : "127.0.0.1",
                "port" : "8081",
                "method" : "HEAD",
                "status" : "200"
            }, etc
```

When stating this query

```
db.http_methods.find({"methods.head.status":"200"}, {"methods.head.$":1}).pretty();
```

I get the following output three times repeated:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591ec4b8e1f71c0caf406f2a"),
    "methods" : {
        "head" : [
            {
                "host" : "127.0.0.1",
                "port" : "8081",
                "protocol" : "http:",
                "path" : "/index.html",
                "method" : "HEAD",
                "status" : "200"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?

EDIT: and with this query

```
db.http_methods.find({_id:ObjectId("591ec4b8e1f71c0caf406f2a‌​"), "methods.head.status":"200"}, {"methods.head.$":1}).pretty()
```

I get an error:

```
  [main] Error: invalid object id: length :
```

Comment: use `db.http_methods.find({"methods.head.status":"200"})` instead

Comment: great, it worked, if you you want to post an answer, be my guest :)

Comment: well...actually the query you suggested returns all values...

Comment: I guess you mean all the value in the array. This is the expected behavior, because mongodb returns all documents where the `head` array contains a doc with `status: 200`. To remove the other, use either **`$unwind`** + **`$match`**, or **`$filter`**

Comment: no, in the complete JSON I have "status":"404", and I get them also. The query you first suggested returns the same as db.http_methods.find()...

Comment: I believe you can use projection. Something like `db.http_methods.find({"methods.head.status":"200"}, {"methods.head.$":1})`. First part to query and second part to return the matched value. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

Comment: ok, this one works @Veeram, but I get three repeated outputs, why?

Comment: Can you add an update to question with your input, query and output ?

Comment: I've updated the question @Veeram

Comment: May you want to narrow down your search to resolve to  single document by adding _id to the query ? Try `db.http_methods.find({_id:ObjectId("591ec4b8e1f71c0caf406f2a"), "methods.head.status":"200"}, {"methods.head.$":1}).pretty()`;

Comment: ok, this one says: [main] Error: invalid object id: length :

Comment: I noticed there are special characters at the end of string value.Try copying them to notepad first and then to your query.

Comment: you're right, the problem is not the query, thanks :)